# What's the difference between BaseView and ModelView in flask-admin

Tags: python-3.x, flask, flask-admin

such as the problem

```
from flask_admin import BaseView
from flask_admin.contrib.sqla import ModelView
```

I've never used flask-admin before. I hope to hear some useful info from you

I guess they're probably the same, but i dont know

Comment: See documentation https://flask-admin.readthedocs.io/en/latest/introduction/. Modelview: Model views allow you to add a dedicated set of admin pages for managing any model in your database.  Baseview: A set of standalone views (not tied to any particular model) can be added by extending the BaseView class and defining your own view methods.